# Check for correct username on custom login form

Tags: login, forms, password, reset

I have used Jeff Star's tutorial for creating my own custom login form http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/. It works great, but I have one problem. On the reset password form, if someone enters their username incorrectly (so that it doesn't verify), they get kicked to the default wp-login.php?action=lostpassword with the error message.

Is there a way to redirect to my own error page?

Thanks!

Comment: In a rush, can `username_exists()` help you somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code he posted in that tutorial (very nice BTW) post's the form to the build-in "reset password" module which redirects to the login.php on error, but you can change that and build your own based on the original and add it to the template page, change:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
    <div class="username">
        <label for="user_login" class="hide"><?php _e('Username or Email'); ?>: </label>
        <input type="text" name="user_login" value="" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="1001" />
    </div>
    <div class="login_fields">
        <?php do_action('login_form', 'resetpass'); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Reset my password'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="1002" />
        <?php $reset = $_GET['reset']; if($reset == true) { echo '<p>A message will be sent to your email address.</p>'; } ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?reset=true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
    </div>
</form>
```

to:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" class="wp-user-form">
<div class="username">
    <label for="user_login" class="hide"><?php _e('Username or Email'); ?>: </label>
    <input type="text" name="user_login" value="" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="1001" />
</div>
<div class="login_fields">
    <?php do_action('login_form', 'resetpass'); ?>
    <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Reset my password'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="1002" />

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['reset_pass']))
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $username = trim($_POST['user_login']);
        $user_exists = false;
        if (username_exists($username))
        {
            $user_exists = true;
            $user_data = get_userdatabylogin($username);
        } elseif (email_exists($username))
        {

            $user_exists = true;
            $user = get_user_by_email($username);
        } else
        {
            $error[] = '<p>' . __('Username or Email was not found, try again!') . '</p>';
        }
        if ($user_exists)
        {
            $user_login = $user->user_login;
            $user_email = $user->user_email;
            // Generate something random for a password... md5'ing current time with a rand salt
            $key = substr(md5(uniqid(microtime())), 0, 8);
            // Now insert the new pass md5'd into the db
            $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_activation_key = '$key' WHERE user_login = '$user_login'");
            //create email message
            $message = __('Someone has asked to reset the password for the following site and username.') . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= get_option('siteurl') . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= __('To reset your password visit the following address, otherwise just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= get_option('siteurl') . "/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key\r\n";
            //send email meassage
            if (FALSE == wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Password Reset'), get_option('blogname')), $message))
            $error[] = '<p>' . __('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...') . '</p>';
        }
        if (count($error) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($error as $e)
            {
                echo $e . '<br/>';
            }
        } else
        {
            echo '<p>' . __('A message will be sent to your email address.') . '</p>';
        }
    }
    ?> 
    <input type="hidden" name="reset_pass" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: looks great, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten this to work great, with just a few changes. There were a couple of syntax errors and the md5 key generator didn't work, so I took the one from wp-login.php. I just have one problem now. When someone clicks the url in the email to create a new password, they're redirected to the default form, so now I need to create a form for that too.

Comment: @pippin: the the md5 key generator code here is the one for wp-login.php, and as for the redirection try adding `&redirect_to=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the link in the email you send.

Comment: My link now looks like this `$message .= get_option('siteurl') . "/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=$user_login&redirect_to=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']\r\n";`, but what's weird is that when I add the &redirect, the message doesn't get sent . . . Also, won't I need to make a new form for the user to enter their new password and such in?

Comment: Yeah i forgot about that, you would need to create your own form to reset the password and probably replace the link that is sent to the user to the current url, and based on the key check if its the user and show him the form.

Comment: line 17 `get_user_by('login', $user_login);` as the `get_userdatabylogin` has been deprecated...

Comment: I realize this answer is quite old, I'm a bit unsure about its reliability. While I guess it should work, I'd rather not mess with SQL since it may change in the future. On the other hand, I can't find details on alternatives.

Comment: " not mess with SQL " ? its copied from the core file nothing more

Answer (score 9):

Here is an updated version of the code from @bainternet with the syntax errors corrected, the suggestion by @Val and the key generator from wp-login.php 3.4.2:

```
global $wpdb;
$username = trim($_POST['user_login']);
$user_exists = false;
// First check by username
if ( username_exists( $username ) ){
    $user_exists = true;
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
}
// Then, by e-mail address
elseif( email_exists($username) ){
        $user_exists = true;
        $user = get_user_by_email($username);
}else{
    $error[] = '<p>'.__('Username or Email was not found, try again!').'</p>';
}
if ($user_exists){
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $user_email = $user->user_email;

    $key = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_activation_key FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s", $user_login));
    if ( empty($key) ) {
        // Generate something random for a key...
        $key = wp_generate_password(20, false);
        do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);
        // Now insert the new md5 key into the db
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $key), array('user_login' => $user_login));
    }

    //create email message
    $message = __('Someone has asked to reset the password for the following site and username.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= get_option('siteurl') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('To reset your password visit the following address, otherwise just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "&redirect_to=".urlencode(get_option('siteurl'))."\r\n";
    //send email meassage
    if (FALSE == wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Password Reset'), get_option('blogname')), $message))
    $error[] = '<p>' . __('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...') . '</p>';
}
if (count($error) > 0 ){
    foreach($error as $e){
                echo $e . "<br/>";
            }
}else{
    echo '<p>'.__('A message will be sent to your email address.').'</p>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was still encountering issues with the reset key not working properly, the link in the email would redirect me to the standard password reset page with the URL parameter indicating a problem with the key, so I more closely followed the wp-login.php file and included the $wp_hasher object, this fixed the problem and the password reset in the email now works

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === (string) 'POST') && (isset($_POST['reset_pass']))) {

// Acccess global properties
global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;


// Variables
$error_pass_reset = array();
$username         = (string) trim($_POST['user_login']);
$user_exists      = (bool)   false;



// ---- USERNAME OR EMAIL EXISTS ---- //
if (username_exists($username)) {
    $user_exists = (bool)   true;
    $user        = (object) get_user_by('login', $username);
} // end if

else if (email_exists($username)) {
    $user_exists = (bool)   true;
    $user        = (object) get_user_by('email', $username);
} // end else if

else {
    $error_pass_reset[] = '<p>Username or Email was not found, please try again.</p>';
} // end else



// ---- USER EXISTS ---- //
if ($user_exists === (bool) true) {
    // Variables
    $user_login = (string) $user -> user_login;
    $user_email = (string) $user -> user_email;


    // Generate password reset key
if (empty($key)) {
    $key = (string) wp_generate_password(20, false);

    do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);


    // Create the $wp_hasher object
    if (empty($wp_hasher)) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php');

        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    }

    // Reset key with hasher applied (MD5 has string output)
    $hashed = (string) time() . ':' . $wp_hasher -> HashPassword($key);


    // Insert the new key into the database
    $wpdb -> update(
        $wpdb -> users,
        array(
            'user_activation_key' => $hashed
        ),
        array(
            'user_login' => $user_login
        )
    );
} // end if


    // Email message
    $message = (string)
    'Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:' . "\r\n\r\n" .

    get_option('siteurl') . "\r\n\r\n" .

    'Username: ' . $user_login . "\r\n\r\n" .
    'If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.' . "\r\n\r\n" .
    'To reset your password, visit the following address:' . "\r\n\r\n" .

    get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=' . $key . '&login=' . $user_login . "\r\n";


    // Send email
    if ((bool) false === wp_mail($user_email, get_option('blogname') . ' Password Reset', $message)) {
        $error_pass_reset[] = '<p>The e-mail could not be sent at this time.</p>' . "\n";
    } // end if
} // end if


// Send the rest password email
do_action('login_form', 'resetpass');

} // end if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === (string) 'POST') && (isset($_POST['reset_pass'])))
```

Comment: This answer with the wp_hasher code was extremely useful to me as I have created a custom forgotten password template.