# Custom login redirects to wp-admin on wrong password

Tags: wp-admin, login

My custom login form redirects to the wp-admin login when an user doesn't manage to guesses his/her credentials right. How can I manage to redirect the user to the current form instead? And of course show the proper errors?

Here is the code: (same as on WordPress manual)

```
$args = array(
        'echo' => true,
        'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username' => 'user_login',
        'id_password' => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
        'remember' => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false ); 

wp_login_form( $args );
```

Comment: Did you tried echoing the site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), because it works fine, I've used it succesfuly ?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-can-i-redirect-user-after-entering-wrong-password

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While coding a custom login page, one needs to take care of the errors, else WordPress would redirect the page to /wp-admin or wp-login.php on wrong passwords or empty credentials. Please follow the below to solve this issue:--

Please use the below in your theme's functions.php file:-

```
/**
 * Function Name: front_end_login_fail.
 * Description: This redirects the failed login to the custom login page instead of default login page with a modified url
**/
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'front_end_login_fail' );
function front_end_login_fail( $username ) {

// Getting URL of the login page
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];    
// if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
if( !empty( $referrer ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-admin' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( LOGIN_PAGE_ID ) . "?login=failed" ); 
    exit;
}

}

/**
 * Function Name: check_username_password.
 * Description: This redirects to the custom login page if user name or password is   empty with a modified url
**/
add_action( 'authenticate', 'check_username_password', 1, 3);
function check_username_password( $login, $username, $password ) {

// Getting URL of the login page
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
if( !empty( $referrer ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-admin' ) ) { 
    if( $username == "" || $password == "" ){
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( LOGIN_PAGE_ID ) . "?login=empty" );
        exit;
    }
}

}
// Replace my constant 'LOGIN_PAGE_ID' with your custom login page id.
```

and the below in the custom login page file to show the corresponding errors:--

```
<div class="wp_login_error">
    <?php if( isset( $_GET['login'] ) && $_GET['login'] == 'failed' ) { ?>
        <p>The password you entered is incorrect, Please try again.</p>
    <?php } 
    else if( isset( $_GET['login'] ) && $_GET['login'] == 'empty' ) { ?>
        <p>Please enter both username and password.</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing ) at `wp_redirect( get_permalink( LOGIN_PAGE_ID ) . "?login=failed"; `

Comment: Having problem with this. [Never assume that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will always be present.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369615/serverhttp-referer-missing)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried echoing the

```
site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

this one works fine, I've used it succesfuly

```
'redirect' => get_permalink()
```

**Update**
For redirect on login failure, you gotta use **wp_login_failed** hook, and some custom code to redirect user to desires page with proper warning message.

```
add_action('wp_login_failed', '_login_failed_redirect');

function _login_failed_redirect( $username ){

  //get your page by slug and then its permalink
  $post = get_page_by_path('slug');

  //Or you can get your page ID, if you are assigning a custom template to a page.
  $redirect_page = !empty ( $post ) ? get_permalink ( $post->ID ) : site_url();

  $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

  if(!$user){
    //Username incorrect
    wp_redirect($redirect_page .'?login_error=1');

  }else{
   //Username Password combination incoorect
    wp_redirect($redirect_page .'?login_error=2');
  }

}
```

And if you are redirecting to some template, you can easily get login_error and display it accordingly.

Comment: User is still redirected to `/wp-admin` when typing a wrong password. Redirect is only for redirection after login.

Comment: Yes I didn't saw it, will give you an update in 15 mins.

Comment: Still the same, sven.

Comment: @Siyah Accepted answer doesn't works for you?

Comment: @sven, it does partially. I am getting a permission error when trying to create a new page. That is unrelated to this code, of course. The issue I have, though, is that I don't find the solution elegant. It is redirecting to a new page, while I'd like to have the errors shown on the same page of where you try to log in.

Comment: That is rather the default functionality. In case creds are wrong WordPress shows it on the login page. So if you are building a custom page, you should be able to handle the errors on same page easily. Also, if it's unrelated to current question you should be posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Maruti for your comment, it's really helped me with the exact same issue!

Where he has written:
"and the below in the custom login page file to show the corresponding errors..."
does somebody know where I can find the login page file? I have a feeling this is a silly question, but I've looked everywhere I can think of, and can't find where to add the div error code?

Thanks for any response!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/260051)