# How to place wp-login.php in page or page template?

Tags: login, page-template, errors, wp-login-form

I want to place the wp-login.php box or page kind of in the templates of the website. As in I want a page which has all of it in.

I did search and found that I can use wp_login_form(). Yes, I've looked into that, but it doesn't display any error messages, and keeps redirecting to wp-login.php. I did look into preventing it from redirecting to wp-login.php, but it still doesn't display any error messages.

I want to either place the entire wp-login.php into the center of the page (between the header and the footer, where the content is) or be able to easily create a login page where the errors are printed automatically by using a snippet or something, because I'm installing plugins over time and they have many new errors that would need tending to.

I have looked into these questions and links already:

[How can I redirect user after entering wrong password?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-can-i-redirect-user-after-entering-wrong-password)

http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-your-own-wordpress-login-page

http://designmodo.com/wordpress-custom-login/

I've also looked at the different wordpress hooks such as the authenticate and login failed as well as signon among others. I'm trying to look for a way. Should I just go ahead and create if statements based on the errors I'm expecting, or is there an easier way to display the errors?

This is what I want to do, basically.
[image: Desired Result]

Thank you so much.

Comment: In default, form using `wp_login_form` redirects to the `wp-login.php`. If you dont want this then you need to do custom coding for submitting form using AJAX and redirect according to the AJAX response.

Comment: Hmm... Can't I somehow pull the wp-login.php into one of my pages or customize the wp-login.php to give it the header and footer of my website? (I'm looking for a JS free solution)

Comment: Plugin `Theme My Login` does what you desire in this case. You can study that plugin how it works. I dont have such deep knowledge about that plugin.