# How can I prevent my custom form from redirecting to wp-login?

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I'm building an application for a client that is accessed via an *email address* and a *project number* - a custom field.

I created a really simple form from scratch (i.e. not using `wp_login_form`), and I validate the posted values with `WP_QUERY`.

My problem is that when the form values are incorrect, or blank, the user is being automatically redirected to the wp-login.php page.

How can I override this behavior and keep the user on the custom log-in page template?

```
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
        <label for="form_email">Email Address:</label>
            <input id="form_email" type="text" name="email" value="" />
        </label>
        <label for="form_project">Project Number:</label>
            <input id="form_project" type="text" name="project" value="" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been covered quite thoroughly here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105224/62906

I've linked directly to the most informative and complete answer of the group (IMO).

Comment: The question you linked to (like almost all that I read prior to posting my question) deals with overriding the default behavior of the `wp_login_form()` function, which I'm not using. Any idea if the processes outlined there would still be valid?

Comment: Yes, only part of the answer I highlighted deals with the wp_login_form() helper. The hooks and custom helpers defined in that answer modify other aspects of the process which are not specific to the native login form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize it through coding then this tutorial is surely gonna help  you. You can easily replace default WordPress login page with your own custom login page.

http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-redirecting-wordpress-default-login-into-a-custom-login-page/