# Prevent redirect on custom wordpress login form

Tags: wp-login-form

I'm having a little trouble with a custom login form that I've created.

```
<?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post" target="_blank">
      <p>
        <label for="log" id="user">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="20" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="password" id="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" />
      </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
      <p>
        <label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/login-tournament/tournaments/"/>
     </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="recovertext"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?    action=lostpassword">Recover password</a></div>
  <div id="loginbox"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/register">Not registered yet?</a></div>
<?php } else { ?>
  <p class="login-text">You're already logged in.<br>Click here to view the <a href="http://MY-CUSTOM-REDIRECT-URL.com" target="_blank">Tournaments</a> page or you can <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout"> Logout</a></p>
<?php }?>
```

A successful login will redirect the user to a custom URL and open the custom url in a new window. (this is working fine)

The problem I have is that if the user enters the incorrect credentials, they are redirected to the default `wp-login.php` form. I need the user to stay on the current page and display an error message. I did find this [snippet to prevent the redirect](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84548/32278) and it does work but it opens up the same page in a new window. Is it possible to prevent the new window opening when the incorrect details are entered. (I still need the new window to open on successful logins)

Further to this, if no login details are entered at all when the login button is clicked, it will also send the user to the default `wp-login.php` page. Is it possible to prevent this also?

Comment: is anyone able to offer any advice on this?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. This fixed it for me.

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );
function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
     $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
     if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin')     ) {
          wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );
          exit;
     }
}
```